# ReportObject Class in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Can someone tell what is reportobjectName in the following line of code and how to get it from a crystal report RPT file?

```
 ReportObject reportObject = Report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[reportObjectName];
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the actual name of the report. Here is an example from MSDN:

```
private ReportObject GetReportObject(string reportObjectName) 
{
     ReportObject reportObject;

     reportObject = 
            Report.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[reportObjectName];
         return reportObject;
}

 GetReportObject("CrystalReports.rpt");
```

[**ReportObject**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms226132%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition

Here is another example of defining the report details and then extracting it using the ReportObjects

[How to find the ReportObjects in Crystal Report using Crystal Reports .NET SDK?](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/01/09/how-to-find-the-reportobjects-in-crystal-report-using-crystal-reports-net-sdk)